# Hibernate Many-To-Many Relationships only visible one way

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

Java 8, Hibernate 4.3.8.Final, Play Framework, SQL Server behind it using the official driver, using IntelliJ 14.1.2.

Basically, I have a set of Users, and a set of AccessGroups.  Groups have users, users have groups, many to many.

Persistent.java

```
package models;

import play.db.jpa.JPA;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;


@MappedSuperclass
public class Persistent implements Serializable{

protected Persistent() {
    this.creationTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    this.modificationTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

protected final static String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

... etc (other getters/setters, persist(), update(), remove() methods, etc)

AccessGroup.java:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "accessGroupId"))})
public class AccessGroup extends Persistent {

    @ManyToMany(        
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, 
        mappedBy = "accessGroups", 
        targetEntity = User.class)
    private Collection<User> users;

    public Collection<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Collection<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
```

...etc (other getters and setters not involved in this relationship)

User.java:
    package models;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;



@Entity
@Table(name = "AppUsers")
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "userId"))})
public class User extends Persistent{
    public User() {};

    public static UserFinder getFinder() {
        return new UserFinder();
    }

    public static class UserFinder extends Finder<User> {

        public UserFinder () {
            super(User.class);
        }

}
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
            targetEntity = AccessGroup.class,        
            cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name="user_groups", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="userId")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "accessGroupId")
            })
    private Collection<AccessGroup> accessGroups;

    public Collection<AccessGroup> getAccessGroups() {
        return accessGroups;
    }

    public void setAccessGroups(Collection<AccessGroup> access_groups) {
        this.accessGroups = access_groups;
    }
```

.... again, other methods not relevant.

persistence.xml

```
 <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="liveDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://#############"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="#############"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="#############"/>

            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Here's the code I use to create a relationship for testing, persisting and updating from the User (owner) side.

```
AccessGroup newGroup = new AccessGroup();
newGroup.setName("The Group");
newGroup.persist();

Collection<AccessGroup> groupList = new ArrayList<AccessGroup>();
groupList.add(newGroup);

User newUser = new User();
newUser.setFirstName("Test");
newUser.setLastName("User");
newUser.setEmail("test@user.com");
newUser.setAccessGroups(groupList);
newUser.persist();
```

The database is recognized and created perfectly.

If I go and run a query to retrieve the User object, I get a proper list of their access groups (in other variations, I've added more than one group), but on the reverse, if I query for AccessGroups, the "Users" list is empty.

The table structure is created as it should be, with the join table called user_groups, holding IDs from the AccessGroup and AppUsers tables.  I've got examples of this running in other frameworks, copied and pasted other examples from the internet for Hibernate m:m mappings, and I can't get any of them to run correctly.

What am I doing wrong?